# Как в Intellij IDEA открыть 2 проекта сразу

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Мне нужно открыть одновременно 2 проекта в Intellij IDEA в двух разных окнах, но чего-то я никак не соображу, как это сделать, подскажите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Очень просто. Описано вот [тут](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/opening-reopening-and-closing-projects.html).

File->Open(выбираете свой проект)-> New Window

Либо заходите в Settings -> Appearance&Behavior->System Settings -> Project Opening. Тут выбираете значение по умолчанию. Открывать в том же окне или в новом окне

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @НиколайСеменов если ответ решил вашу проблему, то нажмите на галочку и стрелку вверх рядом с ним

Comment: @AntonSorokin, **upvote** вроде бы не обязателен. Достаточно **Accepted**

Comment: @Dred не обязателен но приятен